# tibco data format with WSDL message

Tags: wsdl, tibco

I'm using TIBCO Designer. 
I have some problems in create a  WSDL message that use a type defined in a Data Format (Parse Palette).

When I try to validate my WSDL message i get this exception:
"Error: Unresolved reference to element "{http://www.tibco.com/ns/no_namespace_schema_location/Data Format.sharedparse}Rows"."

How I can resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Data Format to define your type. Data Formats are used for reading text files. Instead, define your type using Schema (XML Tools Palette).